# How GA calculate bounce rate ?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am fetching bounce rate month wise and saving in my DB

But for eg. my data is for  JAN - 50% , FEB = 60 % . Which I cross check with GA it is also same ..

But when I find Bounce rate YTD in GA (JAN to FEB) It wont give 50+60 / 2 = 55%

Which mismatch my data ..

Comment: you have taged it v4 are you doing this in android or IOs?

Comment: web api  NODEJS @DaImTo

Comment: Is your data being sampled?

Answer (score 1):

[ga:bounceRate](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_bouncerate)

> UI Name: Bounce Rate
>
> The percentage of single-page session (i.e., session in which the person left the property from the first page).
>
> Calculation:
>
> ga:bounces / ga:sessions

Trying to get any of the calculated fields to work out with our data is never easy.

Answer (score 1):

Bounce rate is the percent of sessions that leave the site without any interaction.  As [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) mentioned, a bounced session will always be a user that left on the first page but not every session that leaves the site on the first page will be considered a bounce.  If any event fires on the first page before the user leaves the site, that session will not be considered a bounce unless the event fired was explicitly specified as a non-interaction event.